# R ggplot2 warns about missing rows/values and drops parts of plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dplyr, missing-data

I've got an R data frame that looks like this:

```
> glimpse(spottingIntensity)
Observations: 28
Variables: 5
$ nClassifications       <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,...
$ nPhotosClassified      <int> 45816, 25252, 12327, 5286, 2327, 1231, 713, 565, 447, 435, 318, 227, 192, 156,...
$ totalClassifiedPhotos  <int> 95781, 95781, 95781, 95781, 95781, 95781, 95781, 95781, 95781, 95781, 95781, 9...
$ proportionOfClassified <dbl> 4.783412e-01, 2.636431e-01, 1.286998e-01, 5.518840e-02, 2.429501e-02, 1.285224...
$ cumulativeProportions  <dbl> 0.4783412, 0.7419843, 0.8706842, 0.9258726, 0.9501676, 0.9630198, 0.9704639, 0...
```

In it, `nClassifications` and `nPhotosClassified` are data and the other variables are derived.

I use the following to plot the data with `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(data = spottingIntensity, mapping = aes(x = nClassifications, y = cumulativeProportions)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    geom_text(mapping = aes(label = nPhotosClassified), nudge_y = 0.03) + 
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(NA, 10), 
                       breaks = seq.int(from =  1, to = 10, by = 1))
```

Which gives me these warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (position_stack). 
2: Removed 18 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

And this output:

[image]

I see that in the plot, the column for `nClassifications = 10` is not shown even though data for it exists in my original data frame.

I checked the data frame, and I do have a few "missing rows" for `nClassifications = 24, 27, 30, 31`, but not for `nClassifications = 10`.

So:

1. Why isn't the bar in the plot for `nClassifications = 10` showing up? How do I fix this? (I expected a bar similar in height to `nClassifications = 9`)
2. How do I programmatically "fill/complete" my data frame so that there are corresponding rows for `nClassifications = 24, 27, 30, 31`? In this case, `nPhotosClassified <- 0` for those four `nClassifications`. And with that I can derive the other variables.

Can `dplyr`/`tidyr` help with 1. and 2.? Or is there another way? Thank you!

**EDIT**: Ooooops, I pasted the wrong code snippet before, it's correct now.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure if it's that simple, but can you try to use different limits in case the bar doesn't show up due to lack of space in the plot? The bar needs some space/area around your last point. Something like `limits = c(NA, 10.5)`?

Comment: For 2, see `tidyr::complete`

Comment: For 1, you could switch your "x" to factors instead of numbers (maybe with something like `forcats::fct_inorder` to get the order right) and set the limits to the values you desire, like `limits = as.character(1:10)` in `scale_x_discrete`.

Comment: Thank you @AntoniosK and @aosmith!! (1) I tried `limits = c(NA, 10.5)` and my desired column does show up, so are the warnings I got simply a result of not enough space in the plot?? (2) I also tried `scale_x_discrete()` which also worked. So at least I can get the visual output to be what I want, but is there any underlying problem or logic I should know about??

Comment: The warnings have to do with the fact that you have NA values and `ggplot` can't use / plot them, so it excludes them. You can exclude NAs from your dataset before you plot it, or find a reasonable way to fill those NAs if it's possible. You can fill them using the comamnd @aosmith suggested, but the value you'll use to replace them depends on you and your application.

Comment: Thanks @AntoniosK, what's a logically formal way to exclude those missing rows (I don't have NAs visible in the data frame, but there are some missing rows for certain x-axis values)? Does that happen in the `ggplot()` call or elsewhere?

Comment: Assuming your dataset's name is `dt` use `dt[!complete.cases(dt),]` to see the full rows that you have NA values somewhere in your columns. Therefore, `dt[complete.cases(dt),]` will remove all rows with NAs and then you can plot this.

Comment: I just tried it, and doing `dt[complete.cases(dt),]` did *not* remove any rows for me... Like I said, none of my row have apparent NAs in any column (easy to check because I only have 28 rows of data in the data frame). *However*, there are missing *rows* for certain x-axis values (see my post for details). How do I fix this?

Comment: OK I see what you mean. Then you should probably try and keep only the rows in your dataset where `nClassifications <= 10`, as those are the ones you're going to plot anyway. Then the `ggplot` commands won't spot any missing rows as you'll have everything from 1 to 10. I think this will resolve the warning issue.

Comment: Got it, will do thanks!!! Sorry to be so inquisitive, but if one day I want to plot something like this along a wider range in the x-axis and it goes over some of those missing rows, how do I fix it?

Comment: You can keep using what you have. A warning is not an error. You can also find a way to hide those warnings if you prefer. Or create them and add a zero value so you can see on the plot that you're missing them.

Comment: Understood, thank you @AntoniosK again for your help and patience!!

Comment: No problem. Before I meant "create the full spectrum of x axis values and add zeros when you have missing info.....".